# Back button in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Is there any way to add back button in `UITableView` ?

I have two tables view when you select `cell` from first table you will be moved to another table. However, when I moved to second table I can't go back to the first table.

Here is the example :

https://imgflip.com/gif/krbwb

as you can see there is no back button in second table :

[image: Second Table View]

and here is my interface builder :

[image: Interface]

Comment: Set both the UITableViewControllers as the children of the Navigation controller. Then the back button will automatically appear when the second tableview is pushed.

Comment: You need to add UINavigationController and make Gesture controller to your rootviewcontroller of the navigation then just use simple sigue for push the new UITableview and you will have the backbutton there in the navigation bar.
You don't need the new navigationcontroller between the gender controller and new tablecontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add navigation controller to root viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Just need little modification in your interface.

Embed `UINavigationController` to your first `UITableViewController` instead of Second table view controller  and remove `UINavigationController` which is between two tableview controller in `UIStoryboard`.

Make `UISegue` from first tableview controller to another controller.

When you go from first tableview to another tableview, it will automatically create default Back button, in `UINavigationBar`.

Enjoy Coding !!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the navigation controller in-between the genders table view controller and boys table view controller, and then select genders table view controller, go to Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigation controller, you have to push the next view controller on navigation controller. Back button will appear automatically. I think you are presenting the view controller modally.

Answer (score 0):

How are you showing the next view ? You should be pushing the new view controller (and not presenting) within a navigation view controller. Also your table view doesnt have a navigation controller which could be a problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to screenshot Navigation Controller is in the middle of 2 controller which is wrong.

Flow should be Navigation Controller then GenderViewController and then your details view controller.

and make navigation controller's RootViewController as GenderViewController.

Hope this will help you.